# Adding routes to a menu made of a list of models

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I have a menu in my flutter app that use a list of model for the navigation and it look like this:

[image: i'm the menu]

When i click on one of the element on the list i want to folow one of the material route, since i did not make the menu and that i have not a lot of knowledge in flutter i have no idea how to do that or if it's even possible.

**Every** suggestion is welcom !!

Here is a view of the custom list:

```
class NavigationModel{
  String title;
  IconData icon;
  NavigationModel({this.title,this.icon});
}

List<NavigationModel> navigationItems = [
  NavigationModel(title: "Dashboard",icon: Icons.insert_chart),
  NavigationModel(title: "Calendar",icon:Icons.calendar_today),
  NavigationModel(title: "terrain",icon:Icons.landscape),
  NavigationModel(title: "professeur",icon:Icons.person_pin),
  NavigationModel(title: "joueur",icon:Icons.person_add),
];
```

sample of the menu builder:

```
children: <prefix0.Widget>[
  SizedBox(
    height: 50.0,
  ),
  CollapsingListTile(
     title: '$nickname',
     icon: Icons.person,
     animationController: _animationController,
  ),
  Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, counter){
        return CollapsingListTile(
          title: navigationItems[counter].title,
          icon: navigationItems[counter].icon,
          animationController: _animationController,
        );
      },
      itemCount: navigationItems.length,
    ),
  ),
  SizedBox(
    height: 50.0,
  )
],
```

Routes in the app:

```
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'Recipes',
  initialRoute: '/connection',
  routes: {
    '/': (context) => Connection(),
    '/connection': (context) => Connection(),
    '/connexion': (context) => Connexion(),
    '/newclub': (context) => NewClub(),
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i get rid of the issue buy getting arround the problem.
What i did is put every element of my list in an InkWell().
With this solution the menu is unchanged and i can do any treatment i want in the onTap().

```
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, counter){
      return new InkWell(
        child: CollapsingListTile(
          title: navigationItems[counter].title,
          icon: navigationItems[counter].icon,
          animationController: _animationController,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          print('button click: $counter');
        }
      );
     },
     itemCount: navigationItems.length,
   ),
 ),
 SizedBox(
   height: 50.0,
 )
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that `CollapsingListTile` widget, I guess it expands when pressed upon? Anyways, for example if you wish to navigate to a route when pressing a `ListTile` widget, you would do this:

```
ListTile(
 title: navigationItems[counter].title,
 icon: navigationItems[counter].icon,
 animationController: _animationController,
 onTap: () {
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SomePage()));
)
```

Comment: What i uderstand is that CollapsingListTile widget is a custom widget made especialy for this menu so it did not implement onTap() .